Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:{require [21.0.0, 23.4.99]; prefer 23.4.0}. React Native

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:{require [21.0.0, 23.4.99]; prefer 23.4.0}.
Required by:
project :app > com.onesignal:notifications:5.1.23
> Failed to list versions for com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging.
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

React Native version: 0.75.4
jdk version: 17
gradle-wrapper: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.8-all.zip
"react-native-onesignal": "^5.2.5",

The JVM doesn't have the required SSL CA certificaes, hence when Gradle tries to connect over https, it's unable to establish a secured connection.
Get the CA certs and add them using keytool and it should start working.
